# value of cell is not recognized as equal to listbox items even though it is

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

My code doesn't recognize cell values as equal to listbox items even though it is. Everything works perfectly until it begins the loop, where it then doesn't consider SelItem the same value as the cell value. I ran the loop seperately without it being part of the Userform sub and here it works fine.
I looked up in Locals window and the SelItem is a Variant/String variable and I guess it should be compatible with a cell value?

Please see code below.

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim SelectedItems As String, LastRow As Long
Dim selItem As Variant, selItems As Variant

For i = 0 To CountryList.ListCount - 1
    If CountryList.Selected(i) = True Then
        SelectedItems = SelectedItems & CountryList.List(i) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next i

If SelectedItems = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select minimum one country"
Else

CountrySelection.Hide

'Create New Sheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
    WS.Name = "Country Selection"


'If Sheet is VeryHidden
Dim WasHidden

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Sheets("Country Split").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        Sheets("Country Split").Visible = xlSheetVisible
        WasHidden = True
    End If

    Sheets("Country Split").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Country Selection").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Format As Table
Set StartCell = Range("D10")

  StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, , , xlYes).Name = _
    "Country_Selection"

producttable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Country_Selection")

    If WasHidden Then Sheets("Country Split").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
SelectedItems = Left(SelectedItems, Len(SelectedItems) - 1)
selItems = Split(SelectedItems, vbNewLine)
```

This is where it read `If Range("F" & i).Value = selItem` as not the same thing even though it is.

```
    For Each selItem In selItems
        For i = 11 To LastRow
            If Range("F" & i).Value = selItem Then Rows(i).Hidden = True
        Next i
    Next
End If

For i = 11 To LastRow
    If Rows(i).Hidden = True Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

Unload CountrySelection
End Sub
```

Comment: Check data types, if you compare string to int it will be different, e.g. string `"1"` will not be equal to int `1`

Comment: Try `If CStr(Range("F" & i).value) = CStr(selItem) Then` but you must be able to check it. Put a stop after this row and see if the code stops on that line...

Comment: ´´´CStr(Range("F" & i).value) = CStr(selItem)´´´ Didn't work either. It still goes straight to ´´´next i´´´ and still states value as same. As I understand the default data type is Variant? Because then it should be comparing Variant with Variant (Cell.value)